# Where am I going wrong with this?

Tags: c

I'm new to C programming. I came across this problem in codechef.
https://www.codechef.com/problems/TLG?tab=statement
I have no idea why it is failing. Please help.

> The game of billiards involves two players knocking 3 balls around on a green baize table. Well, there is more to it, but for our purposes this is sufficient.
>
> The game consists of several rounds and in each round both players obtain a score, based on how well they played. Once all the rounds have been played, the total score of each player is determined by adding up the scores in all the rounds and the player with the higher total score is declared the winner.
>
> The Siruseri Sports Club organises an annual billiards game where the top two players of Siruseri play against each other. The Manager of Siruseri Sports Club decided to add his own twist to the game by changing the rules for determining the winner. In his version, at the end of each round, the cumulative score for each player is calculated, and the leader and her current lead are found. Once all the rounds are over the player who had the maximum lead at the end of any round in the game is declared the winner.
>
> Consider the following score sheet for a game with 5 rounds:
>
> | Round | Player 1 | Player 2 |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 140 | 82 |
> | 2 | 89 | 134 |
> | 3 | 90 | 110 |
> | 4 | 112 | 106 |
> | 5 | 88 | 90 |
>
> The total scores of both players, the leader and the lead after each round for this game is given below:

> | Round | Player 1 | Player 2 | Leader | Lead |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 140 | 82 | Player 1 | 58 |
> | 2 | 229 | 216 | Player 1 | 13 |
> | 3 | 319 | 326 | Player 2 | 7 |
> | 4 | 431 | 432 | Player 2 | 1 |
> | 5 | 519 | 522 | Player 2 | 3 |
>
> Note that the above table contains the cumulative scores.
>
> The winner of this game is Player 1 as he had the maximum lead (58 at the end of round 1) during the game.
>
> Your task is to help the Manager find the winner and the winning lead. You may assume that the scores will be such that there will always be a single winner. That is, there are no ties.
>
> ### Input
>
> The first line of the input will contain a single integer N (N ≤ 10000) indicating the number of rounds in the game. Lines 2,3,...,N+1 describe the scores of the two players in the N rounds. Line i+1 contains two integer Si and Ti, the scores of the Player 1 and 2 respectively, in round i. You may assume that 1 ≤ Si ≤ 1000 and 1 ≤ Ti ≤ 1000.
>
> ### Output
>
> Your output must consist of a single line containing two integers W and L, where W is 1 or 2 and indicates the winner and L is the maximum lead attained by the winner.
>
> ### Sample 1:
>
> #### Input:
>
> ```
> 5
> 140 82
> 89 134
> 90 110
> 112 106
> 88 90
> ```
>
> #### Output:
>
> ```
> 1 58
> ```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int N, a, b, cum1 = 0, cum2 = 0, lead = 0, leader = 0;
    scanf("%d", &N);

    while (N--) {
        scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
        cum1 += a;
        cum2 += b;
        if (abs(cum1 - cum2) > lead) {
            lead = abs(cum1 - cum2);
            leader = cum1 > cum2 ? 1 : 2;
        }
    }
    printf("%d%d\n", leader, lead);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried solving it without the use of array, but it is showing as wrong answer. Unfortunately I don't know the failed test cases either. What can be the reasons for such failure?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I tried solving it without the use of array, but it is showing as wrong answer. Unfortunately I don't know the failed test cases either." This does not leave us with an answerable **question**. Please read [ask], and see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for general hints on debugging logical problems in code. Start by testing the program yourself: **make sure you know what should happen** for the input you provide, and see if it gets the right input. Try different cases until you find something that is wrong.

Comment: If the result is wrong, then the next step is to figure out **what** is wrong about the result. For example, is there some *pattern* to the differences, between the results the program gives vs. what is expected? Then, look for an *explanation* for that difference. If there is not an obvious explanation, then the next step is to look over the program *in parts*, break down what each part should do, and figure out **where** the problem is.

Comment: If the quiz site you use doesn't give proper debugging outputs try the code somewhere else, download a C compiler or use something like ATO to actually get the full output of the program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is at least this problem: you print both numbers without a space in between. The `printf` statement should be changed to:

```
    printf("%d %d\n", leader, lead);
```

You should have been able to diagnose this problem by running your program with sample test data on your system or with an online compiler with a shell window.  Testing and debugging are a must for programming, you must learn these skills early.

Aside from this trivial problem, your code is elegant and simple, the use of arrays is definitely not warranted.

Yet there is a non obvious limitation that might be a problem on some systems: both `N` and all `Si` and `Ti` values are specified with a range that will fit in type `int`, but the cumulative scores might exceed `32767`, which is the largest value the `int` type may handle in some older 16-bit systems.  For maximum portability, you should use type `long`, function `labs()` and the `%ld` conversion specifier.

Here is a modified version with extra sanity checks:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int N, a, b, leader = 0;
    long cum1 = 0, cum2 = 0, lead = 0;

    if (scanf("%d", &N) != 1)
        return 1;

    while (N-- > 0 && scanf("%d%d", &a, &b) == 2) {
        cum1 += a;
        cum2 += b;
        if (labs(cum1 - cum2) > lead) {
            lead = labs(cum1 - cum2);
            leader = cum1 > cum2 ? 1 : 2;
        }
    }
    printf("%d %ld\n", leader, lead);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If this is really the problem, then a) the question should be closed as a typo rather than being answered; b) it is at the very least OP's responsibility to *try* the code, *observe* the wrong result, *describe* a problem and **ask a specific question**. Please read [answer] and do not try to debug code for others without a proper question.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: sometimes obvious bugs hide in plain sight...

Comment: Yes, and posts about such bugs are explicitly not within Stack Overflow's mandate - unless there is an explicit question about the bug, which results from having found the problem and still having some genuine confusion about **why** the code does what it does. If it's a typo, close it as a typo.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: pointing the trivial mistake can be done in a comment... analysing potential problems, which may or may not cause a fail in the posted code, was too large for this comment to contain.  Even the simplest C programs can fail in non trivial ways.

Comment: Sure; and all of that is still off topic and should not be posted on Stack Overflow. If you wish to help people like this, please use an actual discussion forum, such as Reddit or Quora. Stack Overflow has the issue that it should have about 2 million questions, all of which are helpful to other people armed with a search engine; but instead has about 23 million questions, 21 million of which are personal requests to debug a specific piece of code and get it working.

Comment: Thanks you so much. That was the problem, I should have put a space between %d and %d. This is so stupid. I've loosing my mind since morning over this. And I'll use long for big numbers now on. I have not learned the stdlib.h library yet, so did not know about labs() as well. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Not if you have any intention of posting it, no. That is [explicitly banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned).

Comment: @chqrlie Oops, sorry, I didn't know about this feature. I have accepted this answer.